# How to create a temporary table or CTE with values from two sources

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, temp-tables

Need to build a temporary table or a CTE for reporting purposes. Users will be able to select a location and courses from drop-downs.

The tables involved are the Person table that holds all employees and a Common Table Expression that will have the courses selected from drop down.

I need to be able to create a temporary table or a CTE with employee id field from the person table and a course name field from Course CTE.

For example, if courses A, B, C are selected each employee will have three records, one for each Course selected. So employee 1 will have three records in this temporary table or CTE. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Sounds like a great plan. Go get em!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` or `UNION` queries inside CTE to get values from Multiple Tables. So If you want to get the EMployeeId and CourseName for Each employee, YOu can Join the tables inside the CTE like this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        E.EmployeeId,
        C.CourseNm
        FROM dbo.Employee E
            INNER JOIN dbo.Course C
                ON E.CourseId = C.CourseId
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
```

if you want to use Temp tables, you can try this

```
SELECT
    E.EmployeeId,
    C.CourseNm
    INTO #Temp
    FROM dbo.Employee E
        INNER JOIN dbo.Course C
            ON E.CourseId = C.CourseId

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the problem is that employee table does not have a course ID so I wanted to create a temp table that would have an employee record for each course chosen through the prompt. So this table would just have employee ID and course selected

Comment: I added the Course Id for just give you an example. You can use any other column that can be used to link the records based on your table structure